# Check if a PostgresSQL DB Exists with Batch File and Output Custom Values to a Text File

Tags: windows, postgresql, batch-file

Basically I am trying to check if a certain PostgreSQL DB exists with a batch file from the `CMD` in Windows. Then output custom results onto a text file within the same location, the text file will contain custom values. But the batch I created keeps giving me this (below), does not create the file and instead outputs this on the cmd:

> ```
> SET _chk_DB=server
> was unexpected at this time.
> ```

And I would like to know where I went wrong.

I am a beginner with batch so please do take that into consideration.

```
SET _chk_DB=server
FOR /F "usebackq" %%S IN (psql.exe -h %_svr% -d %_db% -U %_usr%
-P %_psw%
-Q "set nocount on; select count(*) from dbo.sysdatabases where
[name]='%_dtb%'") DO (   SET _chk_DB=%%S   )
IF [%_chk_DB%]==[server] 
    "1" >> Info.text 
else 
    echo "0" >> Info.txt
IF [%_chk_DB%]==[login] 
    "1" >> Info.text 
else 
    echo "0" >> Info.txt
IF [%_chk_DB%]==[0] 
    "1" >> Info.text 
else 
    echo "0" >> Info.txt
```

Comment: You specified `usebackq` but there are no quotes, so you need backticks around the command line in between `(`/`)` after `in`; this does not explain the error message though...

Comment: To sum it up, pretty much your syntax for every command is incorrect.  You can read the help to see the syntax usage for each command.  Open up a command prompt and type the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark. example: `for /?`

Comment: @aschipfl I changed it, sadly the error still shows up